# Repeating/looping a clip in the timeline

Tags: premiere, davinci-resolve

I have a short clip, 10 seconds or so. I'd like to loop in/down the timeline to create a 6-hour video (for sleep music on youtube).
I can do this in Davinci with the Loop effect in a Fusion composition. Only thing is it takes a very long time to even pre-render and the CPU is maxed for 4+ hours (Macbook Pro w/ 16g).
Premiere doesn't require that kind of pre-render but I can't find a similar way of repeating. The only answers here are around copy/paste which would take a half hour just to do for this length of video.
Any ideas?

Comment: I vote copy paste. If you [select all] first, then the number of clips pasted doubles with every third keystroke, so it won’t take long. Cmd-A, cmd-C, cmd-V, repeat…. After ten cycles, you’re pasting over a thousand clips. No question, it’s faster than using Fusion.

Comment: You could also always try to loop your player instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you have After Effects, you can set a file to loop indefinitely by right clicking the file and selecting Interpret Footage:

[image: grab]

But I suspect rendering out may take longer than premier for a long comp.

You may find that copying and pasting over and over in Premiere is quicker (ie paste two copies, copy those, paste four copies, copy those, paste 8 copies, etc etc) is quicker than using AE.